# What are the possible causes of wheel damage

Tags: wheels, damage

I have recently bought 4 new 18 inch wheels for my car. Just now, a week later, I noticed two small damages. This week I didn't park near curbs and drove very carefully as I knew how easily the wheels can get damaged.

Does anyone what can cause these small damages occured on the passenger sides wheel?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the curb rash was not there prior to you acquiring the wheels ? There really is no way for us to answer this question.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Yes I bought them fully new from the store.

Comment: NimaJam, that does not necessarily mean that the curb rash was not already there. Did you inspect them at the time of purchase ? Is it two wheels or just two spots on one wheel ?

Comment: Maybe you were not as careful as you hoped you would be...

Comment: I wouldn't call it damage, more cosmetic.  Some clear-coat or clear nail polish may match the appearance of the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

This could almost be anything with the information we are given.

- Could have been slightly damaged when you bought them
- Could have been damaged when the tires themselves were mounted. Some people aren't that careful
- You could have slightly brushed them against something, since they're on the same side